# Special characters are added while writing a string content to file using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, file

I have a scenario, where I have to write the Json content to a file using Jquery.

I am able to write the content to the file successfully, however the file contains some special characters other than my actual contents in between some character of text.

Coding:
I have used the Content document of the Iframe where the content is saved.
Filtered the unwanted character from the text using regular expression
I was able to write the string content of Json to file.
Also enabled the feature to support the UTF & ASCII characters support in document to write.

When I open the file find some special characters.

**Sample:**

**Unwanted character in File content**

**Name:Other뗠**

The actual string content does not have this character, checked during debug and only on writing to a file this characters are added.

Thanks in advance.

**Code for creating a file using JQuery**

```
  var ifd = document.getElementById('scriptExport').contentDocument;
            ifd.open('text/json', 'txt');
            ifd.charset = "utf-8";
            ifd.write(scriptContent.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s",{}:[]"]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, ' '));
            ifd.close();
            document.charset = "utf-8";
            ifd.execCommand('SaveAs', false, scriptFileName);
```

Comment: You should really try to show us what Characters that is added and maybe an attempt on what you have tried so far to solve this yourself

Comment: sorry, but could you teach us how to write to the file using jQuery?

Comment: I imagine the file is being written on server side.. Check how is being opened or created (character encode).

Comment: First of all jQuery will not write the file at the client side? How you done that? It is another thing that you made ajax call from the jQuery to server and at server you are writing file.

Comment: Show your code, It is helpful to us to solve your problem, Without knowing your code no one can be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks all, I have updated the code with unwanted character details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand your problem but if you want to remove all special characters before parsing it to thr json just make sure to add the following code to the string :

```
var str= str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
```

Comment: Yes I have added the same type of regex to remove unwanted character. var finalData =   strContent.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s",{}:[]"]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, ' ') however after writing the content to the file, there are some unwanted characters in file.

Comment: And u sure still find the Special Characters ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by the following,

I have added the same type of regex to remove unwanted character.

```
var finalData = strContent.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s",{}:[]"]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, ' ')
```

However after writing the content to the file, there are some unwanted characters in file.

once after the character are replaced write the content of the updated text Content into the file **`using encoding UTF format`**, which fixed the issue.